# How to find an event to listen to from the outside of a web app to interact with it?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, event-handling, dom-events, mutation-observers

I have a web app loaded in a simple web page containing a single div tag.

```html
<html>
    <script src="https://webapp.company.com/..........."/>
<body>
<div id="webapp"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The web app loads some DOM elements and display them or not.
This is where I would like to be able to capture events to get notified when a DOM node has been created and is visible for modification from outside the webapp.

To give you an insight into the kind of situation it creates ... The loading sequence of the app is the following:

step 1) The app loads a preloader div inside the `<div id="webapp"></div>`, like this:

```
<div id="webapp">
<div class="preloader"></div>
</div>
```

step 2) Then the preloader is removed

```
<div id="webapp">
</div>
```

step 3) The App container is finally added

```
<div id="webapp">
<div class="webapp-content"></div>
</div>
```

If I want to work on DOM Elements available inside `<div class="webapp-content"></div>`, I need first to find an event that would tell me whether the node is loaded or not. As you already guessed, if I listen to a `load` event inside the `window` object, I get notified of the event when the `<div class="preloader"></div>` has been loaded :/

So...I came across some [interesting features on MDN about MutationObserver (2015)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) and tried to implement this to check if I could receive an event ... Eventually, I receive 2 events: 1 when the `<div class="preloader"></div>`has been added (step 1) and another when it has been removed (step 2) but nothing to notify me when the `<div class="webapp-content"></div>` has been loaded (step 3) :/

Once I can do that, if I could do the same kind of things for DOM Elements nested into this `<div class="webapp-content"></div>` that'd be awesome :D

```
<html>
  <script src="https://webapp.company.com/..........." />
  <body>
    <div id="webapp"></div>
    <script>
      //   Select the node that will be observed for mutations
      const webappTag = document.querySelector("#webapp");

      webappTag.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
        console.log("webapp loaded ?");
      });

      //   Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
      const config = { attributes: false, childList: true, subtree: true };

      const callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
        for (const mutation of mutationsList) {
          if (mutation.addedNodes.length > 0) {
            console.dir(mutation.addedNodes[0]);  
            // result: <div class="preloader"></div>        -----> step 1)
          } else {
            console.dir(mutation.removedNodes[0]);
            // result: <div class="preloader"></div>.       -----> step 2)
          }
        }
      };

      const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
      observer.observe(webappTag, config);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So the question is, why does adding `<div class="webapp-content"></div>` not fire a mutation event?

Comment: Yes, and ... is there any kind of event that I'm missing that could be triggered once ```<div class="webapp-content"></div>``` is added?